# Links and Phone Numbers Not Detectable on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview

I have a UITextView that has been created in interface builder so I have written no code for it.  I have checked the boxes for link and phone number detection.  It is not editable and it is selectable.  The problem is that the urls and phone numbers are not clickable unless you tap and hold on the text view.  If you do that, the urls and phone numbers then turn blue and you can tap them.  I have seen that other people are having the same issue and found that disabling scrolling fixes the problem, but I need to be able to scroll, so I'm wondering if anyone has another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in iOS 7.1 beta 3.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  Here is the solution I came up with.  I would love to know if someone else has a cleaner solution.

1. Make the UITextView not editable.
2. Add a tap gesture recognizer for 1 tap.
3. In the action for the gesture recognizer make the UITextView editable and set the cursor position from the tap location.
4. Make the UITextView not be editable when it resigns first responder status.

Here is my tap gesture recognizer action. (This was in a class derived from UITextView so you may need to change self to your UITextView instance.)

```
- (void)onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    self.editable = YES;
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    //We need manually set the cursor on iOS7 since the gesture recognizer picked up the recognizer
    CGPoint pt = [sender locationInView:self];
    NSUInteger glyphIndex = [self.layoutManager glyphIndexForPoint:pt inTextContainer:self.textContainer];
    NSUInteger charIndex = [self.layoutManager characterIndexForGlyphAtIndex:glyphIndex];
    [self setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(charIndex, 0)];
}
```

Comment: Did you file a bug report?  Does the issue persist in the iOS 7.1 betas?

Comment: I did not file a bug report and it is still there in iOS 7.1 beta.